# Django: Get custom tag output inside a view

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a very specific problem.

I wrote a special template tag to display some peace of HTML code based on some calculations. Tag call looks like this:

```
{% chord 'A' %}
```

And the output generated is

```
<div class="chord">A <audio src="/media/chords/A/A.mp3" controls>Not supported</audio></div>
```

Everything works fine, but I came to stage where **I need to put this output inside a variable in my view, not in a template**. Is it somehow possible? Is there a method, that I can call from inside a view, to get custom tag output with a given parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could just define a template string inside your view and render it:

```
tpl = Template("{% load chord %}{% chord 'A' %}")
html = tpl.render(Context())
```

but a better approach might simply be to extract the logic for the tag code into a utility function that you can call both from your view and from the template tag itself.

Comment: Thank you, your answers ar the best as usual :) You also need "from django.template import Template, Context" for this to work